# Disambiguation/rename of [knox] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

(This is not a big deal since it concerns only very few questions)

The tag [knox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knox) (58 questions) denotes questions about an amazon-s3 client for node.js ([here](https://github.com/learnboost/knox)).

Recently, samsung published a new extension to the android platform named [samsung-knox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samsung-knox). Today, there are only 7 questions with this tag (but it will probably attract more questions in a near future). Most of them were misusing the [knox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knox) tag and I already re-tagged them with [samsung-knox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/samsung-knox).

I think the [knox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knox) tag should be renamed to something like [knox-amazon-s3-client]  and [knox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knox) should not be used anymore.

Do you agree ? Any better suggestion for the replacement of [knox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knox) ?

Comment: Why not just [tag:amazon-knox] ?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Probably because it isn't Amazon Knox i.e. a product by Amazon. But a product for Amazon.